# React Native Loader in every component or root?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

Should we use the Loader component (Any custom Loader) in every Component and use dedicated state reducer variables to toggle it with a relative API call or should we have a Loader in the root of the application and toggle it on any API instance?

If we use a root Loader component, and it has properties

```
{position: 'absolute', top:0, bottom:0, right:0, left:0}
```

(Full-screen loader). Although it would get rid of many lines of code to toggle every loader component separately, but wouldn't it stop the user from any other page if one API endpoint crashes or takes too long to load.

What would the best practice be?

Comment: go with hoc component

Answer (score 1):

I wrap all of my screen with custom component, so I have a component that is wrapped all screen and I show loading on this component:

ScreenContainer component:

```
function ScreenContainer({
    barStyle = "dark-content",
    statusBarColor = Colors.whiteFFF,
    children,
    containerStyle,
    loading = false,
    translucent = false,
}: ScreenContainerProps) {
    useFocusEffect(
        React.useCallback(() => {
            StatusBar.setBarStyle(barStyle);
            StatusBar.setBackgroundColor(statusBarColor);
            StatusBar.setTranslucent(translucent);
        }, []),
    );
    return (
        <View
            style={[
                {
                    flex: 1,
                },
                containerStyle,
            ]}
        >
            {loading ? <LoadingOverlay show={loading} /> : null}
            {children}
        </View>
    );
}
```

LoadingOverlay Component:

```
function LoadingOverlay({ show = false }: LoadingOverlayProps) {
    return (
        <Modal
            transparent
            visible={show}
            animated
            animationType="fade"
            presentationStyle="overFullScreen"
        >
            <StatusBar backgroundColor="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" barStyle="light-content" />
            <View
                style={{
                    backgroundColor: "rgb(33, 33, 33)",
                    opacity: 0.4,
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    flex: 1,
                }}
            >
                <TLoader />
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```